# Apple wireless keyboard does not work

Tags: keyboard, apple

I can't write anythying with my Apple wireless keyboard.I am using ubuntu 14.04 and my computer recognizes only keys u,i,o,j,k,l and three others but it writes numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Numlock on Apple Wireless Keyboard

If the Apple Wirelesss Keyboard stops working after log-in where most keys do not work and some keys on the right side produce numbers, it is because numlock is enabled by default. Numlock can be switched off by pressing fn-F6 twice. The keyboard then works normally again.

To disable numlock by default, go to System -> Preferences -> Keyboard -> Layout -> Layout Options -> Miscellaneous compatibility options -> turn on "Default numeric keypad keys"

This setting takes effect after logging in and does not affect the graphical login screen or local consoles.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, pressing fn-F6 twice was not working at all. Im using Ubuntu 20.04 with Apple wireless keyboard German layout.
I figured out by using normal second keyboard to switch off the Num, and then Apple  wireless keyboard works fine. Hope this is help anyone who have the same issue.

Comment: It definitely helps me.

Comment: Cheers buddy for some reason fn+F6 stopped working for me (maybe cause there is a bug in this library https://github.com/free5lot/hid-apple-patched/issues/66 that I used to customise this key). This helped!

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you're like me and have another working keyboard that does not have a numlock key, you can execute `numlockx off` in a console to turn off numlock.

You might need to install it first: `sudo apt install numlockx`

You could of course rig it up to run after login, or map it to a keyboard shortcut (make sure to pick one that works with numlock on)

Comment: Nowadays with Ubuntu 22, this is the only solution I've found. Thanks